# Direct Image Functor Exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a closed embedding (of schemes), so wlog $X \subset Y$. I read that in this case the direct image functor $f_*$ defined on $Y$ by $U \to \Gamma(U, f_* \mathcal{O}_Y) := \Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)$ is exact.

My idea for the proof:

If we have exact sequence 
$0 \to \mathcal{F'} \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F''} \to 0$

that's equivalent to say that is exact on stalks

$0 \to \mathcal{F'_x} \to \mathcal{F_x} \to \mathcal{F''_x} \to 0$

for every $x \in X$.

Because $X \subset Y $

we get for every $y \in Y$: $\mathcal{(f_* F)_y} = \varinjlim _{U \subset Y} \Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)= \varinjlim _{U \subset Y} \Gamma(U \cap X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, so $\mathcal{(f_* F)_y}= \mathcal{F_y}$,  if $y \in X$ and $\mathcal{(f_* F)_y}=0$ otherwise.

So $0 \to \mathcal{(f_*F')_y} \to \mathcal{(f_*F)_y} \to \mathcal{(f_*F'')_y} \to 0$
stays exact for every $y \in Y$.

But this means that $f_*$ is an exact functor if $f$ is an embedding. Why do we need here that $f$ is a CLOSED embedding?

Comment: Think about why is $(f_{*}\mathcal{F})_y = 0$ if $y \in Y$. Here you need that $X \subset Y$ is closed in $Y$.